# How to set a DIV or LI "class" by day of the week?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, html, html-lists

If I have a 7 day calendar with a DIV and UL for each day, how can I add the class of "today" to the LI "day" for the day of the week?  (i.e. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.)

Basically I just want to highlight the day of the week on the page load.

I assume this can be accomplished with jQuery, but I am just getting the hang of it, so any suggestions to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the basic HTML I am using for the content:

```
  <div id="main_content">
   <div id="weekly_schedule">
     <ul class="day_container">
       <li class="day">Su</li>
       <li class="day_content">content</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="day_container">
       <li class="day">Mo</li>
       <li class="day_content">content</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="day_container">
       <li class="day">Tu</li>
       <li class="day_content">content</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="day_container">
       <li class="day">We</li>
       <li class="day_content">content</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="day_container">
       <li class="day">Th</li>
       <li class="day_content">content</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="day_container">
       <li class="day">Fr</li>
       <li class="day_content">content</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="day_container">
       <li class="day">Sa</li>
       <li class="day_content">content</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your html static, not dynamically generated ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: do you want "su" to be highlighted if today is sunday, or do you want all the day of the week to be highlighted?

Comment: The HTML containers will be static, but the content will be dynamically generated.

Comment: @DG3 I want to change the background of just the LI with Su on Sunday, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like the following:

```
$('li.day:eq(' + new Date().getDay() + ')').addClass('today');
```

Comment: your solution is so much simpler. In the OPs question, the first li is a sunday and I don't think you will need "-1", as it will return Thursday, today being Friday. I hope i could think this way, i was using switch case statement by using getDay() of the date object.

Comment: @DG3 Correct, I'd actually removed the `-1` :)

Comment: BOOM! Simple and easy solution.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/colemande/QHMgR/1/) hope it helps. If you have questions let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dayOfWeek = new Date().getDay() - 1;
var selectedUl = $('#weekly_schedule:nth-child(' + dayOfWeek + ')');
// Do whatever you want with selectedUl, such as .addClass('highlighted')
```

Comment: from what i know dayOfWeek will be 1 based whilst the indexing is 0 based. isn't that the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without jQuery and just use plain JavaScript:

```
var date = new Date().getDay()*2;
document.getElementsByTagName('LI')[date].parentNode.className += " today";​
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ndQ59/1/)**.

Comment: This assumes the given `<li />` elements are the only ones in the entire document, probably not a safe bet.

Comment: This seems like the easiest solution, but why am I receiving the error  "illegal character" with an "â€‹" at the end of the script when I check it in Error Console?

Comment: @NewWorldOrderly - The error is on your site or the jsFiddle?

Comment: I copied the code from jsFiddle and when I test it on my site I get the error.

Comment: @NewWorldOrderly - Perhaps something in the copy/paste went wrong. Typing it in should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I came up with the following solution using JavaScript (though I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it).

HTML:

```
<div id="days">
  <ul>
    <li id="mon">Mon</li>
    <li id="tue">Tue</li>
    <li id="wed">Wed</li>
    <li id="thur">Thur</li>
    <li id="fri">Fri</li>
    <li id="sat">Sat</li>
    <li id="sun">Sun</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dayOfWeek = today.getDay();
  if (dayOfWeek == 0) {
    document.getElementById("sun").className = "today";
  } else if (dayOfWeek == 1) {
    document.getElementById("mon").className = "today";
  } else if (dayOfWeek == 2) {
    document.getElementById("tue").className = "today";
  } else if (dayOfWeek == 3) {
    document.getElementById("wed").className = "today";
  } else if (dayOfWeek == 4) {
    document.getElementById("thur").className = "today";
  } else if (dayOfWeek == 5) {
    document.getElementById("fri").className = "today";
  } else if (dayOfWeek == 6) {
    document.getElementById("sat").className = "today";
  } else {}
}

startTime();
```

So this basically adds the class "today" to the li tag depending on what day it is.

You can see the full working example here on my codepen - http://codepen.io/AdamCCFC/pen/XbNyeY